# Call a form from a herited controller

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have two Bundles:
**MainBundle**: Who have the different part of my website.
**SecondBundle** with a form to encode different offers.( The offer Bundle )

My problem is that I want to call my offer form controller in my main page twig of my MainBundle.

I have no problem to call the Form but the data of my form don't save in my DB. On the other side, if I put my Form in my Main Controller, I have no problem and it save all the data correctly.

*The form twig code :*

```
{{ form_start(form,{'attr': {'id': 'FootForm'}}) }}
<div class="field-warper">
    {{ form_label(form.titre, "Titre") }}
    {{ form_widget(form.titre,{'attr': {'placeholder': 'Titre'}}) }}
</div>
<div class="field-warper">
    {{ form_label(form.contenu, "Contenu") }}
    {{ form_widget(form.contenu,{'attr': {'placeholder': 'Contenu'}}) }}
</div>
<div class="field-warper">
    {{ form_label(form.price, "Price") }}
    {{ form_widget(form.price,{'attr': {'placeholder': 'Price'}}) }}
</div>
<div class="field-warper submit-warper">
    {{ form_widget(form.send,{'attr':{'class':'submit'}}) }}
</div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

*My main page twig :*

```
{% extends "DellexisMainBundle:Common:base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}
    <div>
        <p>i'm the Body</p>

        {% block formu %}
            {{ render(controller('DellexisOfferBundle:Offer:index')) }}
        {% endblock %}

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

*My offer controller ( The form controller ) :*

```
class OfferController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity_manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $offer=new Offer();

        $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form', $offer)
            ->add('titre','text')
            ->add('contenu','textarea')
            ->add('price','text')
            ->add('send', 'submit')
            ->getForm();
        // on joint la requete Post à notre classe
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isValid()) {
            $entity_manager->persist($offer);
            $entity_manager->flush();
        }

        return $this->render('DellexisOfferBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
}
```

*My main controller :*

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('DellexisMainBundle:Home:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

*routing.yml*

```
dellexis_offer:
    resource: "@DellexisOfferBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"
    prefix:   /offer

dellexis_main:
    resource: "@DellexisMainBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"
    prefix:   /
```

*OfferBundle routing.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <route id="dellexis_offer_homepage" path="/offer">
        <default key="_controller">DellexisOfferBundle:Default:index</default>
    </route>
</routes>
```

*MainBundle routing.yml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <route id="dellexis_main_homepage" path="/">
        <default key="_controller">DellexisMainBundle:Default:index</default>
    </route>
</routes>
```

**EDIT :**

With a dump of the request of my OfferController and a dump of my DefaultController ( Main Bundle ), the POST method is on the DefaultController, the OfferController stay on a GET method.

**EDIT 2 : THE SOLUTION :**

I finaly find the solution. As the second controller didn't have the same request that the first controller. I think to forwark the request to the second controller. And the magic of symfony wants that works !

So if someone has the same problem, just forward the request like that :

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $this->forward('DellexisOfferBundle:Offer:index', array(
            'request'  => $request
        ));

        return $this->render('DellexisMainBundle:Home:index.html.twig');
    }
```

Comment: can you post your routing configuration file? it seems like the `DefaultController` have no added value to you code or you have different routing config for each Bundle.

Comment: I have edit the post

Comment: I updated the answer!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should have different routes suffixes, Because you use the same one (`\`) in the two  Bundles, witch is bad idea. You can add a suffix to the offerBundle routing config (`\offer`).

Also, in the routing.yml, you didn't load the offerBundle routing config file.

And, by looking at you controller, There is nothing to save.
The indexAction shows the page and save a empty object `new Offer()`.

You have to distinguish between POST Request (when you submit the data) and the GET Request (when you want to show the form)

you code should be something like this:

```
class OfferController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)  {
      $entity_manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

      $offer=new Offer();

      $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form', $offer)
        ->add('titre','text')
        ->add('contenu','textarea')
        ->add('price','text')
        ->add('send', 'submit')
        ->getForm();
      // on joint la requete Post à notre classe
      $form->handleRequest($request);

      if($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->isValid()) {
        $entity_manager->persist($offer);
        $entity_manager->flush();
      }

      return $this->render('DellexisOfferBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
          'form' => $form->createView()
      ));
  }


}
```

Comment: I tried what you say but nothing had changed. But with the $form->isValid(), it save nothing if there are no data in the form so there is already a verification between GET and POST method no ? I have put dump in the controller to see if the offer variable have the value of the POST but the variable still have the null value. So i think it detect no POST method

Comment: With a dump of the request of my OfferController and a dump of my DefaultController ( Main Bundle ), the POST method is on the DefaultController, the OfferController stay on a GET method.

Comment: So it doesn't work even the update of my routing.yml but i find the solution and put it in my post ! Thanks for your help !

Comment: @ThomasClermont That would be excellent. Thanks for sharing with community.